# Fastify + Swagger $ref usage in routes

Tags: node.js, swagger, swagger-ui, fastify

How should I use the $ref when defining routes?
This way it throws: FastifyError [Error]: Failed building the serialization schema for GET: /route, due to error Cannot find reference "Data"

Created a mock:

```
 await app.register(swagger, {
        openapi: {
            openapi: '3.1.0',
            info: {
                version: '1.0.0',
                title: 'Example app',
            },

            components: {
                schemas: {
                    Data: {
                        type: 'object',
                        properties: {
                            name: {type: 'string'},
                        }
                    },
                }
            }
        }
    });

   await app.register(() => {
        app.get('/route', {
            schema: {
                response: {
                    200: {
                        type: 'object',
                        $ref: 'Data',
                    }
                }
            }
        }, (request: FastifyRequest, reply: FastifyReply) => {
            return reply.status(200).send({'name': 'Works'});
        });
    })
```

I want to use $ref in the routes too, to make sure I won't double define things (SSOT) and make clear links in Swagger UI between routes and schemas.

Comment: If you replace `$ref: 'Data'` with `$ref: '#/components/schemas/Data'`, does it work?

Comment: Fastify has some issues with ref data. For example: https://github.com/fastify/fastify-swagger/issues/795